# How to Convert Fixed Point Number to Decimal Number in Python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, fixed-point

How do I convert a signed 64.64-bit fixed point integer to a `decimal` number in python?

For example the integer 1844674407370955161600 which is a signed 64.64-bit fixed point represents the decimal number +100.00, my understanding is that a python `float` has insufficient bits(only 18) to represent the fractional part, hence my choice of the `decimal` type.

Perhaps a more general function for converting `Qm.n` to a `decimal` can be provided.

Comment: I don't understand how your integer became the decimal number 100.00 ?

Comment: @aSaffary look into how fixed point numbers work, here's an online converter, enter 64 for Q and 100.00 for the floating point number and you'll see:
https://www.rfwireless-world.com/calculators/floating-vs-fixed-point-converter.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decimal.Decimal` and divide by the fixed point like so:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(1844674407370955161600) / (1 << 64)
Decimal('100')
```

Keep in mind you'll need at least 39 digits for full precision. Make sure you set it before you start converting:

```
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 39
```

Answer (score 0):

A different option is to use fractions, which will offer full precision as well:

```
>>> import fractions
>>> fractions.Fraction(1844674407370955161600, 1<<64)
Fraction(100, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, you can use [fxpmath](https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath) module to convert a `Qm.n` fixed-point type:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

x_fxp = Fxp(1844674407370955161600, dtype='Q64.64', raw=True) # a fixed-point object

x_float = x_fxp.get_val() # or just x_fxp()
```

> 100.0

If you want a more short code:

```py
x = Fxp(1844674407370955161600, dtype='Q64.64', raw=True)()
```